# How to split a string inside List

Tags: scala

i wonder how to split a string inside list like from list like this: `List(Kat Borth, Gerhardt Dach,`
i want  something like this: `List(List[Kat, Borht], List[Gerdaht, Dach])` because later i would like to compare only the names, and at the end return the full name.
Both this: `l.foreach(e => e.mkString("").toList)` and `l.foreach(e => e.split("").toList)` returns `()` ;/

Answer (score 2):

`foreach` is used to procure side effects but no result, such as if you wanted to print every element in the list or create a bunch of files or something outside of Scala's purview. If you want to return values, you need to use [`map`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#map%5BB%5D(f:A=%3EB):List%5BB%5D).

```
l.map(e => e.split("").toList)
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks. There are so many methods for collections and i can't figure out which one i should choose every time ;/

Comment: @disshethard I am not sure about "every time", but if you master `map` and `flatMap`, that should take care of about 95.3% of your needs.